# Cannot get the getCallbackTokenAsync to function correctly

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am a newbie to outlook js. I am developing a very simple add-in. The add-in simply will forward a selected email to a defined email address. So we click a button and forward the message. My command handler gets called, but that is about all I have gotten to work. The first problem is the authorization does not appear to work. I have followed the example on  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api.

The permission in my manifest is set to ReadWriteMailbox.

```
var accessToken;

Office.onReady(info => {
    // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
    Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function(result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            accessToken = result.value;
        } else {
            accessToken = "error";
        }
    });

});

function MyButtonClick(event) {
    const message = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: "Performed action.  Access token: " + accessToken,
        icon: "Icon.80x80",
        persistent: true
    }


    Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

    event.completed();
}
```

I have tried moving the getCallbackTokenAsync all around, but it seems not to work properly. The accessToken is always undefined.

I have been messing with this for the past day. So I am assuming I am missing something.

We are primarily targeting Outlook 2016 on the mac and windows 10.

Any thoughts?

Tom

Comment: This does sound a bit familiar, I had an issue a couple times where the path in the manifest changed but the client hadn't refreshed, and therefore the audience didn't match and had a similar result.  Try tracing what is going on with Fiddler, you may see some more specific errors in the response headers.

Comment: On another note, do you really need readwritemailbox, otherwise I would suggest readwriteitem - it is easier because you can install as a user.  Also recommend testing with the web browser client which seems to refresh the manifest quicker than putting a new manifest in administratively, or with Outlook that has a local cache somewhere under LOCALAPPDATA where it caches manifests and resources.  If you do update the manifest when testing with Outlook, be sure to update the version number.

Comment: Are you using Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync in case of a compose scenario? The API returns null if the item has not been saved or is not available as draft.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I found the problem and it was a javascript error that clearly showed on the web version. That said, I am back in business